# AJAX is not triggered when TIME of date_popup element is changed

Tags: drupal-7, datepicker, drupal-forms, drupal-ajax

I have a date_popup form element with date and time parts:

```
$form['date_time'] = array(
'#type'          => 'date_popup',
'#title'         => 'Date and time',
'#date_format'   => 'd/m/Y H:i',
'#ajax' => array(
   'wrapper'  => 'date_time_ajax',
   'callback' => 'date_time_ajax_callback',
   ),
);
```

The problem is that ajax callback is only called when date part of the element is changed. When I change time part, nothing happens.

Am I doing anything wrong?